How to separate corrected query by using comma
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = 'learnbiopython@gmail.com'

# espell package
record = Entrez.read(Entrez.espell(db='pubmed', term='Bos gaurus, Antelope cervicapra, Gazella bennettii, Boselaphus tragocamelus, Canis lupus, Panthera leo, Elephas maximus, Equus africanus, Panthera pardus, Cervus canadensis, Pavo cristatus, Grus leucogeranus, Vulpes vulpes, Rhinoceros unicornis, Panthera Tigris, Crocodylus palustris, Gavialis gangeticus, Equus caballus, Equus quagga, Babalus bubalis, Sus scrofa, Camelus dromedaries, Giraffa camelopardalis, Hemidactylus flaviviridis, Hippopotamus amphibius, Macaca mulatta, Canis lupus, Felis domesticus, Acinonyx jubatus, Rattus rattus, Mus musculus, Oryctolagus cuniculus, Bubo virginianus, Passer domesticus, Corvus splendens, Acridotheres tristis, Psittacula eupatria, Molpastes cafer, Eudynamis scolopaccus, Columba livia, Naja naja, Ophiophagus hannah, Hydrophiinae, Python molurus, Ptyas mucosa'))

print(type(record))
for key in record.keys():
  print (key, ':', record[key])


Here's the result:
enter image description here
is it posible to separate the CorrectedQuery record by a comma? and how would it be
i've tried using .join but its not as i expected

could CorrectedQuery be a single string? in that case maybe record['CorrectedQuery'].replace(" ",", ")
